# Compare 2 large string arrays between client/server

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a big string array which has between 24-32 random characters (which include `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]';/.,<>?}{`). Some times the array is empty, but other times the array has more than 1000 elements inside it.

I send them to my client, which is a browser, via AJAX every time he requests them and I want to reload a part of my application only if that array is different. That means if there was a modification, adding/removing in said array. So I want to send the entire array, and some kind of hash of all the elements inside it. I can't use md5 or anything like that because the elements inside the array might move around.

What do you suggest I do? The server uses Java to serve pages.

Comment: Are you saying that the order of the 1000+ strings are not relevant? That `["aaa", "foo", "xyz"]` is the same as `["xyz", "aaa", "foo"]`, but different from `["aaa", "foo", "bar"]`? If so, then sort them and use MD5.

Comment: @Andreas Yes. So the "hash" should be the same for `["aa", "bb", "cc"]` and `["bb", "cc", "aa"]`

Comment: Since order doesn't matter, sorting them will not matter, except that MD5 of a sorted array will stay consistent, even if original order is different. Whether you just always keep the array sorted, or you just sort temporarily for the MD5 is up to you.

Comment: @Andreas I thought about that, but sorting could be expensive and I prefer to do it more scaleable, as I might respond to a lot of requests later on.

Comment: Hence my suggestion of keeping the array sorted, so you don't have to keep redoing it. You might even want to keep the MD5 hash cached too.

Comment: What sort of scaleable do you want? Do you scale for throughput, or client-side performance? Or do you keep it all in memory? You can't have all. 
If you don't want to keep a separately sorted array, you could use a linked list of the items separately.

Comment: Sorting a 1000 element long array on a server is definitely not an expensive operation. But an alternative option is to store an extra field next to it with your modification count that is incremented every time your array is changed. (Make sure it's thread-safe if your array is modified from multiple threads.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure transmitting 1000 characters is actually a problem in your use case? For instance, this stackoverflow page is currently 17000 bytes large, and stackoverflow makes no effort to only transmit it if it has changed. Put differently, transmitting 1000 characters will take about 1000 bytes, or 1 ms on a 1 MBit connection (which is slow by modern standards ;-).

That said, transmitting data only if it has changed is such a basic optimization strategy that it has been incorporated into the HTTP standard itself. The HTTP standard describes both time based and etag based invalidation, and is implemented by virtually any software or hardware interacting using HTTP, including browsers and CDNs. To learn more, read an [tutorial by Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en) or the [normative specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html).

You could be using time based invalidation, either by specifying a fixed lifetime or interpreting the If-Modified-Since header. You could also use an ETag that is not sensitive to ordering, by putting your elements into a particular order (e.g. through sorting) before hashing.

Comment: (Not 1K `char`s, but `String`s, to the order of 30Kbytes(UTF8), if I get the question right.) Using HTTP standardised caching support seems the way to go. There are `If-Modified-Since` header fields for requests (just before `If-None-Match` - not quite sure the document you linked describes correct use thereof).

Comment: The question is not very clear on what data is being transmitted, but even 30KB is transmitted very quickly :-). Curious that the Google tutorial would not describe `If-Modified-Since`, I linked the spec for a complete description.

Comment: I would suggest `ETag` in this case. The "surely my array won't change twice in a single microsecond" assumption is very alluring but wrong. Don't be that guy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a system that allows you to skip sending the strings altogether if the client has the latest version. The client keeps the version number (or hash code) of the latest version it received. If it hasn't received any strings yet, it can default to 0.

So, when the client needs to get the strings, it can say, "Give me the strings if the current version isn't X," where X is the version that the client currently has.

The server maintains a version number or hash code which it updates whenever the strings change. If it receives a request, and the client's version is the same as the current version, then the server returns a result that says, "You already have the current version."

The point here is twofold: prevent transmitting information that you don't need to transmit, and prevent the client from having to compute a hash code.

If the server needs to compute a hash at every request rather than just keeping a current hash code value, have the server sort the array of strings first, and then do an MD5 or CRC or whatever.